# Laptop Asus Integrated Webcam is disabled

Tags: laptop, asus, webcam

I've searched around google for this problem, but all solutions weren't successful on my PC.

So the situation is this:

```
    :~$ lsusb
Protocol spec without prior Class and Subclass spec at line 17509
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04ca:3010 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see `lsusb` doesn't read the webcam
BUT:

```
    :~$ dmesg | grep video
[    9.046002] asus_wmi: Backlight controlled by ACPI video driver
[  444.990641] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[  445.046291] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  709.912127] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB Camera (0bda:57b5)
```

dmesg does.

So, I read that could be a shortcut that I pressed by mistake.

Like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, but didn't work.

Comment: I cannot even find the Camera device in `dmesg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out line beginning with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet...." and put the below instead. Afterwards, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1 acpi_enforce_resources=lax"

In case it doesn't work, run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo -1 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend'
```

Reboot.  Good luck.